# jQuery Mobile (1.1): disable hiding of a fixed navbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.1 and I have a fixed toolbar but I want to disable hiding it when a user clicks somewhere in the page. It would even be better if I can set that up for just specific page elements (like clicking on an input box).

I tried many methods that I found on the web (e.g. `$.fixedToolbars.setTouchToggleEnabled(false);`) but none of them work, probably because of the 1.1 version.
You can check my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Leqpw/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The using is the JQM v 1.0.x method for disabling the fixed toolbar. There are multiple ways to disable this functionality.

The simplest way is to simply add data-tap-toggle="false" to your toolbar. But if you don't feel like copy and pasting a bunch of times in your project try these other methods.

`$('[data-position=fixed]').fixedtoolbar({ tapToggle:false});`

You can also configure it so that certain elements will ignore this behavior.

`$('[data-position=fixed]').fixedtoolbar({ tapToggleBlacklist: "a, input, select, textarea, .ui-header-fixed, .ui-footer-fixed" })`

**Update** added more info for a more complete answer.

Comment: Why was this voted down?! ... Anyways, thanks, this works like a charm and also gives me the ability to selectively disable hiding.

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is add the following attribute to your header

```
data-tap-toggle="false"
```

and the tap toggling will go away.